# Xenophobic aliens kill themselves rather than interact with humans

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

What is the name of the science fiction book where the aliens are so xenophobic that the whole species kills themselves rather than interact with humans?  I can't recall the circumstances, but I think it might be the end of a war between humans and the aliens.

Comment: This is a bit thin on details, do you remember when you read it or what the cover looked like?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if you can add any other details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It may be that there are too many options, but the one that leaps to mind is the Pitar from Alan Dean Foster's [Dirge](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22103).

[image: Cover of Dirge]

Selectively quoting the plot summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirge_(novel)):

> Humanity has recently discovered the planet Argus V, better known as Treetrunk, with the intention of colonizing the planet when their survey team is visited by **a new alien race, the Pitar**. At first the humans worry that the Pitar will want to lay claim to the planet, but instead of wanting to claim territory, the aliens instead simply want to observe the humans.
>
> While the three races continue their political dance, a massacre occurs on Treetrunk. All 600,000 humans are killed by unknown attackers who then leave the planet. After an extensive search for the murderers turns up no clue, a single survivor is found hiding in a lifeboat on the smaller of Treetrunk’s moons. Allwyn Mallory claims to have witnessed the massacre and has proof of the attacker’s identity, a memory sphere that recorded the Pitar not only killing the humans on Treetrunk, but also eviscerating the females for the reproductive organs.
>
> At first the Pitar deny the accusation, claiming that a single man’s accusations are groundless, but presented with the video proof the few Pitar on Terra at first flee, then **either commit suicide when confronted or attack** the humans attempting to place them under arrest resulting in their deaths.
>
> [...] when a ground invasion of the Pitar’s homeworld was begun, the arrogant aliens refuse to surrender, fighting even when the obvious result would be death. None would willingly be taken alive, and **those who were trapped either fought to the death or retreated into a voluntary, terminal madness**. This results in the eventual extinction of the Pitar. Only after the Pitar are exterminated is it discovered why they had eviscerated the women on Treetrunk: they were an incredibly narcissistic people, and couldn't stand the thought of other life forms. They wished to **exterminate humanity and all of the other races**, who they viewed as inferior and undeserving of life. However, they were unable to produce enough offspring to mount such an attack.

Comment: I think I remember this event being mentioned in passing in one of the other Humanx Commonwealth books before Dirge was written, but it's been a decade or so since I've read them.

Comment: @notovny Probably the one that introduces Bran Mallory and Truzenzuzex; it talks about stingships and how they were devloped in the Pitaran war.  I believe that was probably *The Tar-Aiym Krang* but I'd have to go look it up to be sure.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It is in _The Tar-Ayim Krang_, as it came up in this [Google Books preview](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Tar_aiym_Krang/p6JdGr_PcU4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=flinx+pitar&pg=PT118&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I think this is it, especially since I own this book.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This does fall under the description as given.

In the backstory of *Decision at Doona* by Anne McCaffrey, the Siwannese all committed suicide after first contact.  As a consequence, there was to be no further first contact.  (The novel itself is about two races both going to colonize a planet at the same time, thus violating the rule.)

Comment: This is the *other* one I immediately thought of. :)  I picked *Dirge* because this episode happens entirely off-screen and there wasn't a war.

Comment: @Mary Just in case you didn't know you can use markdown instead of HTML when formatting posts. That means you can use `_` or `*` for italics rather than `<I>` tags.

Answer (score 5):

This is an element of John Scalzi's *Old Man's War*. There is an alien race, the Consu, which is extremely xenophobic and is aligned against humankind (albeit in a largely indirect way). The galaxy is constantly at war, though the humans and the Consu are not directly involved in a conflict against one another.

They ultimately agree to a meeting with a human character, but build a special facility just for that meeting. The "ambassador" they send is a criminal who had disgraced itself in battle, and as a portion of its punishment it is assigned to speak in the humans' language while meeting with them. The ambassador craves death for having sullied itself so. Afterwards, the entire facility is imploded and launched towards a black hole so that its contaminated atoms will never trouble the universe again.

Comment: Note that there's absolutely no danger of the Consu *as a species* ever suiciding.  The only reason that anyone ever beats them in the battles they instigate (for fun) is because they handicap themselves enough for there to _be_ a chance that they might lose.  (Otherwise where's the fun?)

Comment: Quite a few stories feature this trope of hyper-xenophobic aliens individually committing suicide after being forced into contact with "tainted" or "inferior" species. Off the top of my head, the Ekhat (specifically, the Interdict faction) in Eric Flint and K.D. Wentworth's _The Course of Empire_ certainly display this behavior. But I believe this question was about a species-wide suicide, not about just a few individuals.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Given what little we see in *Old Man's War* it's certainly possible that the entire Corsu species would destroy itself rather than interact with humanity (every individual we see outside of combat that interacts with humans claims to commit suicide). Notably, your comment could fit the top-rated answer as well, given that it doesn't include species-wide suicide either. The querent gave very few details, and so will have to wade through a variety of answers, all but one of which will not be the book they have in mind. The question is extremely thin on details.

Comment: @Upper_Case But the Consu aren't xenophobic per se.  They only eschew other species because they don't believe they have "evolved" (probably not the best word) to the point of being worthy of contact with the Consu as per their religion.  And one minor plot point across the books is that the Consu are trying to manipulate events between the species in order to force that "evolution".  The suicide by various Consu is portrayed as an act of cleansing themselves after contact with the "unclean"

Comment: @PeterM I'm not sure that the specific reason the Corsu refuse to interact with "lesser" species is a factor which dismisses their xenophobia, especially when it's a cultural explanation-- real-world examples of xenophobia tend to feature xenophobes with substantial "rational explanations" for why their xenophobia is legitimate. If your society won't abide someone that has spoken directly with a member of a species (which is, as a whole, "unclean"), to the extent that suicide and physical annihilation are the obviously correct responses, that sounds xenophobic enough.

Comment: @Upper_Case However the overall intent of the Consu is to bring lesser species into the realm of the Consu.  IMHO that is not a rationalization of xenophobia.

Comment: @PeterM *Shrug*. So they claim. They want lesser species to gain some indefinable, spiritual quality which those species are apparently unable to observe, through methods those lesser species don't understand, and in the mean time any interactions are *so bad* that any Corsu must immediately die and any matter that has been touched needs to be utterly destroyed. "Your religion is wrong, someday it might be the same as ours, but until you're less fundamentally unclean we won't suffer you." IDK how you're defining xenophobia, but I doubt it's much worth parsing this out further here.